# csvreader[] with \multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, csvsimple

I would like to create this table imported by `csv` file. My problem is to create some multirows in the table. Like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage{csvsimple}

\usepackage[landscape,   margin=3cm,left=1cm]{geometry}%\usepackage{lscape} %pacote pagina horizontal
 %\usepackage{adjustbox}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
% \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{array,longtable}

 %permite centrar os dados ao centro da tabela
 \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
%encoding
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=12cm]{logotipo_novo.png}}

\usepackage{color}

%--------------------------------------

%Portuguese-specific commands
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
%--------------------------------------

%Hyphenation rules
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{mate-mática recu-perar}
%--------------------------------------

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}


\begin{document}      
    \hspace{1cm}
    \begin{longtable}{|M{1.5cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|M{2.3cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|}

    \caption*{Departamento de Matemática e Ciências Experimentais}\\\hline
     & Organização & Atividade & Responsáveis & Interveniente & Escola & Enquadramento & P.Educativo & Articulação & Custo & Aprovação\\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    %\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\ldots continued}\\\hline
    \hline
     & Organização & Atividade & Responsáveis & Interveniente & Escola & Enquadramento & P.Educativo & Articulação & Custo & Aprovação\\\hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    \hline
    %\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{continued \ldots}\\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot

    \hline
    \centering
    \csvreader[
    column count=11,
    %no head,
    table head=\hline,
       late after line=\\\hline 
    ]{mat.csv}{
      1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three, 4=\four,
      5=\five, 6=\six, 7=\seven, 8=\eight,
      9=\nine, 10=\ten, 11=\eleven
    } 
     {\one & \two & \three & \four & \five & \six & \seven & \eight & \nine & \ten & \eleven}

    \end{longtable}

    \end{document}
```

How can I change on my code to make the `multirow` on my table?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please add the necessary packages to compile the example?

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage[landscape,   margin=3cm,left=1cm]{geometry}%\usepackage{lscape} %pacote pagina horizontal
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{array,longtable}
 \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

Comment: Please edit the information in your question, instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your `\multirow` in your `\csvreader` command list.

You didn't provide an example of your `csv` file, so I have invented it. I presume it actually has 12 columns (with the last one being the text to be put in the multicolumn of the second row).

I used `example-image-a` instead of your background image.

`filecontents` package and environment are only used to create my `mat.csv`. Of course, you do not need them in your actual document, since you already have your file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape,   margin=3cm,left=1cm]{geometry}%\usepackage{lscape} %pacote pagina horizontal
%encoding
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%Portuguese-specific commands
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
%--------------------------------------

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
 %\usepackage{adjustbox}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
% \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{array,longtable}

 %permite centrar os dados ao centro da tabela
 \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
 \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=12cm]{example-image-a}}

%\usepackage{color} xcolor loaded afterwards

%Hyphenation rules
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{mate-mática recu-perar}
%--------------------------------------

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mat.csv}
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,multicolumn
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k, something
l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v, something else
w,x,y,z,0,1,2,4,5,6,7, and something else again
I,have,invented,this,file,because,you,do,not,provide,an, example of your csv
I,presume,it,actually,has,12,{colums,},not,only,{11,},and, that the last one is a description
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}      
    \hspace{1cm}
    \begin{longtable}{|M{1.5cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|M{2.3cm}|M{2cm}|M{2cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{1.5cm}|}

    \caption*{Departamento de Matemática e Ciências Experimentais}\\\hline
     & Organização & Atividade & Responsáveis & Interveniente & Escola & Enquadramento & P.Educativo & Articulação & Custo & Aprovação\\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    %\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\ldots continued}\\\hline
    \hline
     & Organização & Atividade & Responsáveis & Interveniente & Escola & Enquadramento & P.Educativo & Articulação & Custo & Aprovação\\\hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    %\hline
    %\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{continued \ldots}\\
    \endfoot
    %\hline
    \endlastfoot

    %\hline
%    \centering
    \csvreader[
    %column count=11,
    %no head,
    %table head=\hline,
       late after line=\\\hline 
    ]{mat.csv}{
      1=\one, 2=\two, 3=\three, 4=\four,
      5=\five, 6=\six, 7=\seven, 8=\eight,
      9=\nine, 10=\ten, 11=\eleven, 12=\mydescr
    } 
     {\multirow{2}{*}{\one} & \two & \three & \four & \five & \six & \seven & \eight & \nine & \ten & \eleven\\\cline{2-11} & \multicolumn{10}{l|}{\mydescr}}
    \end{longtable}

    \end{document}
```

[image]